# Flutter FutureBuilder with Isar DB not refreshing

Tags: flutter, flutter-isar

I have a simple app that lists a bunch of items that are saved in Isar DB:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var body = Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        const SizedBox(height: 2.0),
        Expanded(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<Item>>(
            future: getAllItems(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Item>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                // If there was an error while fetching the data, show an error message
                return Center(
                  child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                var items = snapshot.data!;
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: items.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ItemRowCard(
                      item: items[index],
                      onRowTap: () async {
                        // tapping the row takes you to edit the item name
                        dynamic result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/edit_item', arguments: {
                          'item_name': item.name,
                          'item_id': item.id
                        });
                        if (result != null) {
                          setState(){}; // should cause the build function to rerun
                        }
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text('No data found.'),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

The `getAllItems()` uses Isar db to fetch data:

```dart
  Future<List<Item>> getAllFolders() async {
    final isar = await db;
    final items = await isar.items.where().findAll();
    return Future.value(items);
  }
```

This works BUT whenever I add or edit an item (see the `onRowTap` call), the page refresh does not show the change unless I insert a delay of 1 second or so before I call `setState` after getting the result.

What am I missing? I am at my wits end over this :). All Isar calls are async with await, so techically they should return AFTER the DB operation finishes, and I should be able to call the setState without manually adding delays!

Comment: Try to add a `setState` in the `.then()` - See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76415451/12349734

Comment: No difference :(

Comment: You have a typo: `setState();` should really be: `setState(() {});`

Comment: Sorry, corrected. The code is write, I seem to have removed it when removing unneeded code to post here! Though that is not the issue :)

Comment: I think you need to use a [watcher](https://isar.dev/watchers.html) if you want realtime updates, and you can use a `StreamBuilder` instead of a `FutureBuilder`